# Sidebar Menu en mini dashboard basico

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Necesito hacer un side bar, este ya lo tengo con un ejemplo de Bootstrap funciona correctamente, pero el punto es que en las pestañas del sidebar no se como hacer que aparezcan en pantalla principal algo así como un dashboard basico, hice un barmenu el link en un proyecto el link es minornotepad.000webhostapp.com, tiene 3 pestañas en horizontal pero necesito la misma funcionalidad pero en el sidebar, no se si alguien puede ayudarme, decirme algun tutorial o de alguna manera
Una disculpa por la molestia

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo usar vertical pills de Bootstrap:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/#v-pills-tab

Puedes activarlo con JavaScript:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/#via-javascript

Desde el inspect realicé la prueba, adjunto las imágenes para que puedas ver como queda.

[image: Pill 1]
[image: Pill 2]

Comment: El código va como texto por favor

Comment: Muy bien, deja ver que onda con eso de bootstrap, si funciona te doy como correcta tu respuesta, gracias